# Bug Fixing. OpenGL, GLSL sprite grid rendering Issue

Tags: c++, c, opengl, graphics, glsl

This is a very specific case and I'm running out of ideas.

I am trying to render a grid of sprites without using positions as instance data per sprite. This can be done using the gl_InstanceID variable.

The World is made up of **Chunks (16 * 16 * 2(2 because there are two sprites/instances per position))**. All Chunks are being drawn correctly themselves, but not all at the right position relative to another.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

I am using a width and a height, to specify when a new line begins. Here you can see the bottom left corner when positioning the camera at the right place (no problems)

[image]

When positioning the camera slightly off, then this is drawn:

[image]

Now the bottom right corner.

[image]

Note the width = 3 (returned by a printf statement) which clearly says, that there shouldn't be a 4 columns (but there is).

That's the problem in a nutshell.

I'm almost certain the problem lies in the GLSL code (shader), because i checked all the values i sent over to the graphicscard and their offsets. I feel like the problem is in the way glsl computes the positions of the chunks.

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec2 v_pos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 v_uv;
layout (location = 2) in float uv_index;

layout (std140) uniform Matrices
{
    mat4 view;
    mat4 projection;
};
uniform uint diagonalSpriteCount; //used for the uv indexing (of no interest here)
uniform uint chunksOnScreenRow; //what you saw as width on the pictures
uniform vec2 camOffsetToFirst; //this specifies the position to the first instance to be rendered

out vec2 uvCoordinates;

void main()
{
//////////////////////////////////////////
//THIS IS PROBABLY THE ONLY RELEVANT PART FOR YOU
    //i devide the index by two, as only every second instance the position changes
    int posIndex = gl_InstanceID / 2; 
    //every 256 Positions (16 * 16) a chunk is complete, thus the next chunk begins
    int chunkIndex = posIndex / 256;
    //the position of the vertex, first basic quad information and an offset
    gl_Position = projection * view * 
    vec4(v_pos.xy + camOffsetToFirst + 
        vec2(
            //this specifies the x within the chunk
            mod(posIndex, 16)    
                //this is the offset on the x axis, 
                //which depends on which chunk (the chunk the instance belongs to) is currently being rendered 
                //chunksOnScreenRow = width that you saw on the pictures
                + 16 * mod(chunkIndex, chunksOnScreenRow), 
            //this is the position on the y axis, relative to the first element of the current chunk
            floor(mod(posIndex, 256) / 16)   
                //same like with the x axis, offset on y depending on current chunk
                + 16 * floor(float(chunkIndex) / chunksOnScreenRow)
        ), 
    0.0, 1.0); //this is just the rest of the vec 4
//////////////////////////////////////////
    //irrelevant for you
    uvCoordinates = v_uv / diagonalSpriteCount + vec2(
        uv_index / diagonalSpriteCount - floor(uv_index / diagonalSpriteCount),
        floor(uv_index / diagonalSpriteCount) / diagonalSpriteCount
    );
}
```

And here the way the data is structured in case you need it.
[image]

Now I'm asking for your help, if you happen to know what might cause such a weird behaviour. If you can help me find the reason to this behaviour i would be forever grateful.

EDIT: Each block that you see in the picture is a single chunk. You won't be able to see the individual instances

EDIT: Apparently if i remove the float() around the chunkIndex in the second vec2() parameter the offset still hapens, but one up
[image]

Comment: At first glance this appears to be an off-by-one error, possibly introduced in the modulo method.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why your chunk depicted is only 6x6? Or am I missing something?

Comment: No sorry, guess i should have specified that better. I have coloured each chunk with the same texture, thus each instance in the chunk shares the same texture. I did this, so you can more easily see the chunk borders. So what you are seeing are 6*6 chunks. But thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Can you tell me the value of `camOffsetToFirst` each of the 3 pictures, also the output of `chunkIndex` if you can. Assuming `projection` `view` are static in your tests, those are the only 2 variables that could be going wrong here.

Comment: @Enfyve The chunkIndex is on the GPU. Unfortunately i can't read it. I can only guess or calculate it on the CPU. The projection is somewhat static (zoom dependent) it does change the max width, but does not directly affect which chunk is drawn. The view matrix also changes the frustrum, thus increasing the width. In the end its all related to the width the screen is currently showing. I figured out that the issue comes with a width of 3 or if i change the total number of chunks to a 20 by 20 then even 6, 7, 9 , 12, 13, 14, 15... however from there up to 20 it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figured it out. If a Off by One error (like Enfyve called it) comes up don't trust the built in glsl mod() functions, as it converts the variables into flats on the way and messes things up on the way.